# SwiftUI - setting the frame of view

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I learn new stuff like SwiftUI (beta 6)
I want to start from the basic.

I just want to set frame to subview like in UIKit.
What I'm missing here ? (this is from Simulator)

**1. the subview is not in 0,0 position.**
 2. why at least the start of the word is not inside the border ?

[image]

UPDATE :
**how to set the text view in 0,0 position ?** (just like on UIKit)
I thought my question is very clear, but for some reason, it's not.

Comment: remove .poistion text will be in center

Comment: but I don't want it to be in center . I want it on 0,0 position

Comment: Then use spacer

Comment: @Fabian where to add spacer ?

Comment: Below the Text inside the VStack.

Comment: @Fabian and this will set the Text border on position 0,0 ?

Comment: Who know, it's a comment not an answer.

Comment: I did not know it's so hard to set frame of 0,0,50,100 in swiftUI like on UIKIt. left-top corner :S

Comment: It's not hard. It's different.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it's important to understand why your solution doesn't work because at a first glance it seems correct and it seems that SwiftUI works in some weird ways (because, of course, we are all used to `UIKit`). 
You tried:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
                .position(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                .frame(width: 50, height: 100)
                .border(Color.red, width: 4)
        }
    }
}
```

And you got:

[image]

First of all, the `position` modifier says:

> Fixes the **center** of the view at the specified point in its **parent**’s
>   coordinate space.

Two things are important here:

- The view is moved based on its centre, not based on its top-left corner
- The view is moved in the parent's coordinate space

But who is the Text's parent? A `view modifier` in SwiftUI is something that applies to a `View` and returns a `View`. Modifiers are applied from the last one to the first one (in reverse order respect to how you see them). In your case:

[image]

So: The **centre** of the `Text` is positioned at (0,0) respect to a `Frame` 50x100 with a red `Border`. The resulting View is placed in the centre of the screen because of the `VStack` (it's the `VStack` default behaviour). In other words: the `position`'s parent (`position` returns a `View`, every modifier returns a `View`) is the `Frame` 50x100 placed in the centre of the screen.

If you want to position the top-left corner of the `Text` at (0,0) in the `Frame` coordinate space you should use the `Spacer` modifier this way:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: 50, height: 100)
        .border(Color.red, width: 4)
    }
}
```

And you'll get:

[image]

If you want, instead, the top-left corner of the `Frame` to be at (0,0) respect to the whole `View` I think the simplest way is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World")
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 100)
                    .border(Color.red, width: 4)
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

And you'll get:

[image]

Comment: This is PERFECT answer. Amazing explanation. Thank god / sun / whatever that  someone finally  understand exactly what I meant. This will help a lot of developers. THANK YOU !

Answer (score 0):

Do Like this way

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello World")
                .frame(width: 50, height: 100)
                .border(Color.red, width: 4)

            .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Below is output

[image]

if you want to remove space on top add  `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` for your view like below

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello World")
                .frame(width: 50, height: 100)
                .border(Color.red, width: 4)

            .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

Comment: not working well . you forgot  .position(x: 0, y: 0) .

Comment: add .position(x:0, y:0) and see it's now working like UIKit

Comment: thanks for your help. I just want simple label 0,0,50,100 with simple border that will show EXACTLY like UIKit.